# How to load all data into picker view

Tags: json, swift, xcode10.2

How to load all data into picker view, now I can load first data only
this is my data from JSON​ response

**jsonResponse ==> Optional([["PlanDate": 18/01/2019, "PlanDateFullFormat": 20190118], ["PlanDateFullFormat": 20190119, "PlanDate": 19/01/2019]])

jsonArray ==>[["PlanDate": 18/01/2019, "PlanDateFullFormat": 20190118], ["PlanDateFullFormat": 20190119, "PlanDate": 19/01/2019]]

jsonDictionary ==>["PlanDate": 18/01/2019, "PlanDateFullFormat": 20190118]

planDate ==> 18/01/2019. ==> I want load all plant date into picker view

Loop json ==> (key: "PlanDateFullFormat", value: 20190118)

Loop json ==> (key: "PlanDate", value: 18/01/2019)**

I cannot load all data into picker view

```
func getPlanDatetoPickerview(ptruckID: String)-> Void {
        .....

                //check data shipment for json Dictionary
                let planDate: String = jsonDictionary["PlanDate"] as! String
                print("planDate ==> \(planDate)")

                //show on pickerView
                for myplanDate in jsonDictionary{
                    print("Loop json ==> \(myplanDate)")
                }//for
                self.getpPlandate = [jsonDictionary["PlanDate"] as! String]
                .....
            }catch let myerror{
                print(myerror)
                //          check display plandate in database
               ....
                }//DispatchQueue
            }//catch
        }//task
        task.resume()
    }//getPlanDatetoPickerview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm assuming your pickerView is set up properly but you are only seeing one row? If that's the case that's probably because of this line of code:**

```
//change array to dictionary
guard let jsonDictionary:Dictionary = jsonArray.first else{
     return
}//guard
print("jsonDictionary ==>\(jsonDictionary)")
```

You are only getting the first element of your array.

What I would do instead is just use jsonResponse directly like this:

```
var planDates = [Any]()
if let jsonResponse = jsonResponse {
   for dictionary in jsonResponse {
      planDates.append(dictionary["PlanDate"])
   }
}
```

Then you can use planDates to populate your pickerView.

**Or maybe, you are trying to load a pickerView with data from a dictionary?**

First, your ViewController has to subclass `UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate`.

Then in ViewDidLoad, set your ViewController as the delegate/datasource for your UIPickerView:

```
repeatPicker.delegate = self
repeatPicker.dataSource = self
```

Then implement your Delegate/Datasource methods:

```
   // The number of components of your UIPickerView
   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        // Return number of planDate entries
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    }
```

Comment: I think this line, How to I fix this 
guard let jsonDictionary:Dictionary = jsonArray.first else{
     return
}//guard

Comment: You are basically getting an array of Dictionaries, so you need to treat it as such. If you use `.first`you are only getting the first element which is a Dictionary and you are missing on all the rest of the data. Use this instead: `var planDates = [Any]()
if let jsonResponse = jsonResponse {
   for dictionary in jsonResponse {
      planDates.append(dictionary["PlanDate"])
   }
}`

Comment: your code is worked, then if when clicking list on picker view,  my label does not change with the value picker view
var planDates = [Any]() if let jsonResponse = jsonResponse {
                    for dictionary in jsonResponse {planDates.append(dictionary["PlanDate"]!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //show on pickerView
                            self.getpPlandate = planDates as! [String]
                            //Show on monitor
                            self.getpPlanDatePickerView.text = planDates as! [String]}} }

Comment: That is probably an issue with your code inside `titleForRow`. Can you post your delegate/data source methods and especially that one? It should look something like this: `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
return planDates[row]
    }`

Comment: this is my code titleForRow func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let titleRow = (getpPlandate[row])
        return titleRow
    }

Answer (score 0):

Actually its pretty easy to load data to a picker view. It's like `UITableView`.

```swift
class YourViewController {

    var yourArray: [YourObject] = []
    var yourPicker = UIPicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        yourPicker.dataSource = self
        yourPicker.delegate = self
    }

}

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDataSource

extension YourViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return yourArray.count
    }

}

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

extension YourViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return yourArray[row].title
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, I have all function same you suggest, but my picker load first data only if you see JsonArray plan date have 2 value
why my picker it loads first data only...